# How to make pre-loaded swf fill the browser?

Tags: html, actionscript-3, flash, preloader, preload

Let me explain my question a bit.

I am creating a flash website and I am using a small external preloader swf to load in the main swf. I have been able to get my preloader swf to take up the whole browser window but as soon as it loads in the main swf it only displays in its normal dimensions that it was built in.

I do have a resize listener within the main flash application and as soon as I change the size of the browser the main swf then occupies the whole browser. But how can I get it to start out that way?

-I've tried using an ENTER_FRAME handler but that broke some of my animations.
-I've tried setting the width and height of my loader object in the preloader and that      doesn't seem to work either.
-I've also tried adding an ADDED_TO_STAGE listener to the loader, but that doesn't seem to have changed anything.
-I also tried having the preloader be in one scene and the main application be in another so that I was only loading one swf, but that didn't seem to work and I don't prefer that method of pre-loading.

I haven't been able to find a solution anywhere. Is there something easy that I'm missing? Let me know what you all think. preloader code is as follows:

```
import flash.net.URLRequest;
import flash.display.Loader;
import flash.events.Event;
import flash.events.ProgressEvent;

var request:URLRequest = new URLRequest("flashNew.swf");
var loader:Loader = new Loader();


loader.load(request);
this.addChild(loader);


function loadProgress(event:ProgressEvent):void
{
    var percentLoaded:Number = event.bytesLoaded / event.bytesTotal;
    var percentLoadedBar:Number = Math.round((event.bytesLoaded / event.bytesTotal) * 100);
    percentLoaded = Math.round(percentLoaded * 100);

    this.percentLoaded.text = String(uint(percentLoaded)) + "%";

    progressBar.width = percentLoadedBar * 3.36;
}

function loadComplete(event:Event):void
{
    //loader.content.height = stage.stageHeight;
    //loader.content.width = stage.stageWidth;
}

function setDimensions(event:Event):void
{
    loader.width = stage.stageWidth;
    loader.height = stage.stageHeight;
}

loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, loadProgress);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, loadComplete);
loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, setDimensions);
```

Is there a way I can change via javascript or something? I'm at a loss here and I've been stuck on this for hours. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

**UPDATE**
Here is my code for my resize function.

```
function resizeListener(e:Event):void
{
    background_mc.width = stage.stageWidth;
    background_mc.height = stage.stageHeight;
    //The rest of the function is omitted. It is if's and else-if's that just reposition various elements.
    //That's really all this function does is re-position elements with the exception of the above code which resizes the background.
}
```

Here is the event listener call.

```
stage.addEventListener(Event.RESIZE, resizeListener);
```

Comment: It would be good if you updated your question to include your code for resizing your swf in the html page.

Comment: not related to your problem but a good practice, is to add your loader.contentLoaderInfo event listeners BEFORE you call loader.load()

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

removed this line of code:  `this.addChild(loader);`

then tweak your `loadComplete` function to this:

```
function loadComplete(event:Event):void
{
    addChild(loader.content);
    loader.content.height = stage.stageHeight;
    loader.content.width = stage.stageWidth;
}
```

Comment: do you have your page accessible somewhere for me to look at?

Comment: Yes. Go to: http://istanek.com/SoundRehabStudios/index.html As you can see when the new swf is loaded in it does fill the browser (at least not mine at 1920x1080) and you can see some of the elements I have hidden off stage. I know I could hide them with alpha or visible but this was easier for the time being.

Comment: actually it works fine for me the first time (I also run 1920x1080), then i resized my window and refreshed and it didn't work.

Comment: might have to do with your child swf, if it's dimensions change after it's created.    to test that, try a delayed call to setDimensions in the loadComplete handler.  eg: setTimeout(1500,setDimensions) ;

Comment: Hmmmm, interesting. Could these be the culprit? stage.scaleMode = StageScaleMode.NO_SCALE; stage.align = StageAlign.TOP_LEFT; I do have those in the main application. They are in there to help make sure the elements re-position correctly on a resize, or so I am to believe anyway. Will try out your other suggestion. Thank you for all of your help!

Comment: You want those in there (other wise your swf will just stretch to fill the area). just make sure they are in both your parent and child swf

Comment: Adding stage.scaleMode and stage.align into parent swf cause it to not be centered in the browser. But adding in your delayed call to setDimensions suggestion has yielded some interesting results. Page is updated if you don't mind taking a look.

Comment: It's throwing a security sandbox error.  apparently your child swf is trying to load another swf from http://s.ytimg.com/yt/swfbin/watch_as3-vflejHtaS.swf.

Comment: do you have your .fla posted somewhere?

Comment: Sorry for the slow response. Work. Yes, that's correct. It's because I'm loading a youtube player into a movie clip in the child swf. Googling that error and such gave me some things about cross domains that I really wasn't completely sure of, so I started focusing on a different part of the project. The youtube player works so I didn't really think that would be the culprit.